# How to bootstrap Windows hosts with remote PowerShell for use with Ansible?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, cloud, ansible

I haven't found a decent way to get a Windows instance in Azure started up using the `azure_rm_virtualmachine` module with remote PowerShell enabled from first boot.

What is the typical approach to get started with Azure Windows instances provisioned with Ansible ready to run PowerShell remote commands?

There's another Ansible module called simply `azure`, but appears to be deprecated by `azure_rm_virtualmachine`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get VM status by using PowerShell. If yes, you could use Azure PowerShell.  `(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $RmVM -Status).Statuses.Code[1]`

Comment: I mean using ansible to provision a host that has remote power shell enabled from first boot to be usable by ansible. I'll clarify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the VM, use [`azure_rm_deployment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_rm_deployment_module.html) module to create a deployment for a Custom Script Extension.

In the template specify:

```
{
  "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
  "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
  "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
  "settings": {
    "fileUris": [
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
    ],
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
  }
}
```

Then run a play against the VM.

Comment: Much appreciated @techraf , thanks also for question edits!